# Firmar un xml con Xades-Bes tipo RSA con algoritmo SHA-256

Tags: c#

Hola amigos como estan necesito firmar un xml con la extension Xades-Bes y firmas tipo RSA con algoritmo SHA-256.
Alguien tiene me puede ayudar?

Comment: Entiendo que esta pregunta es la misma que ya realizaste anteriormente. No debes volver a repetir la pregunta, en todo caso puedes añadir mas información a tu anterior pregunta para tratar de atraer mas atención sobre ella. Un saludo.

Comment: En la página 34 tienes información de la firma https://www.juntadeandalucia.es/agriculturaypesca/clientesfirma/3_1_0/documentacion/firmas_xml_1_1.pdf     y aquí tienes una librería completa de la firma Xades-Bes desarrollada para .Net   https://github.com/ctt-gob-es/FirmaXadesNet